# Dynamically add div over image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a website plugin that will display additional information over images in a div - lets call it `wrapper`. The `wrappers` will be added and later loaded on many external pages dynamically. That's why I have to meet some strict requirements.

The `wrapper` **always** should **exactly** overlap the image (needed for proper positioning items in this `wrapper`). Especially in the following cases:

1. When page content changes (page's elements sizes and positions accordingly) the `wrapper` should still overlap it's image
2. When image size changes
3. When user changes resolution / zooms in / zooms out the page

I need to handle the case when page uses chained (?) style rules like so:

```
.someelement img{ important styles }
```

I think this disqualifies wrapping an image with a div as it would break the original image style.

What will be the right way to go?

**EDIT**

A little clarification on wrapping image with additional div. Lets say the client wants to modify image styled this way (a rectangle):

```css
.myclass p img{
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myclass">
  <p>
    <a href="stackoverflow.com">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

If I wrap the image with `img-holder` like Praveen Kumar suggested the image looses it's original style (now it's a square). It turns out that the **paragraph** tag breaks it.

```css
<!-- client css, cannot be modified -->
.myclass p img{
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
}

<!-- my css, can be modified -->

.img-holder {position: relative; display: inline-block; z-index: 1;}
.img-holder .img-mask {position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 2; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);}
.img-holder img {display: block; position: relative; z-index: 1;}
```

```html
<div class="myclass">
  <p>
    <a href="stackoverflow.com">
      <div class="img-holder">
        <div class="img-mask">Mask</div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
      </div>
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the image with a parent `div` of `inline-block` display and well... I can show the demo here:

```css
.img-holder {position: relative; display: inline-block; z-index: 1;}
.img-holder .img-mask {position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 2; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);}
.img-holder img {display: block; position: relative; z-index: 1;}
```

```html
<div class="img-holder">
  <div class="img-mask">Mask</div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>
```

- The parent should have `inline-block` display to adjust according to the image.
- The image should have a `block` or `inline-block` display to make sure it doesn't put any extra spaces.
- The mask should have `position: absolute`.

This will expand to the size of the `img` as well as it fits the image correctly. Check it out.

Comment: But it doesn't solve the problem with breaking the original image styles like that: .someelement img{ important styles }

Comment: @gisek Can you please clarify?

Comment: Please see the edit. It looks like the paragraph tag (which i forgot to mention before) is crucial here.

Comment: @gisek You cannot have anything inside a `<p>` tag other than running text.

Comment: See the edit now (added <a> tags: `<p><a><img/></a></p>`). This is a real life example where my original script failed. I'm not the author of this html. This is an external page that used my plugin and I cannot force them to improve their html quality.